# Enlarge single symbol (/) in R expression

Tags: r, plot

I have the following code:

```
plot(x = 1, y = 1, xlim = c(1,2), ylim = c(1,2),
     ylab = expression(bgroup("(",A[B]^{C},")")[~D[2]] / bgroup("(",E[F]^{G},")")[~H]))
```

Which leads to this plot:

[image: rplot]

Is it possible to make the division symbol ("/") taller so it properly divides two expression and doesn't look like it's shooting out of D<sub>2</sub>?

My attempt at manually drawing it with cex>1 lead to an ugly and fat division symbol. I don't want it fatter, just taller.

I am looking for solutions that use base plot methods.

Comment: suspect not... `?plotmath` -> "The supported ‘scalable delimiters’ are `|` `(` `[` `{`, `lceil`, `lfloor` and their right-hand versions. "

Comment: @mathematical.coffee yes, but `/` is not a delimiter so I'm hoping for a way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using `latex`, you can export the plot using `tickz`.  That will unleash the full power of latex formatting.  E.g. with a standard sized division sign it looks like this:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('daqana/tikzDevice')
library(tikzDevice)

tikz('test.tex', width = 4, height = 3)
par(mar=c(3,6,3,3))
plot(x = 1, y = 1, 
  xlim = c(1,2), ylim = c(1,2),
  ylab = '$(A_B^C)_{D_2} / (E_F^G)_{H}$')
dev.off()
```

[image]

or if you want an even bigger division sign, you can use one of the latex codes (in ascending order of size) `\big/`, `\Big/`, `\bigg/`, or `\Bigg/`:

```
tikz('test.tex', width = 4, height = 3)
par(mar=c(3,6,3,3))
plot(x = 1, y = 1, 
  xlim = c(1,2), ylim = c(1,2),
  ylab = '$\\left(A_B^C\\right)_{D_2} \\bigg/  \\left(E_F^G\\right)_{H}$')
dev.off()
```

[image]